# How to add a new column that includes sum consecutive values of other column?

Tags: python

I am new to python. I want to create a column in pandas that includes the sum of consecutive values of a column. For example, let's assume we have the following table

| id | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 |
| 2 | 32 |
| 3 | 55 |

And I want to have this table

| id | A | New column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 21 |
| 2 | 32 | 53 |
| 3 | 55 | 108 |

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you attempted to figure this out? What algorithm are you using to convert from column `A` to `New column`?

Comment: Can you share a code to get the dataframe? With a code it is easier to help

Comment: I'm asking how you managed to get the values in the new column? (I assumed that there was an algorithm in play since the first row was the same in both columns)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas running total column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67378629/python-pandas-running-total-column)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is called a cumulative sum. You can just set `df["C"] = df["A"].cumsum()`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html