# Python Pandas running total column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I have a df I want to add a running total column to

| date | F1 | F2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-1 | 10 | 5 |
| 2020-12-3 | 9 | 6 |
| 2020-12-4 | 7 | 16 |

Expected output:

| date | F1 | F2 | F1 Running Total | F2 Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-1 | 10 | 5 | 10 | 5 |
| 2020-12-3 | 9 | 6 | 19 | 11 |
| 2020-12-4 | 7 | 16 | 26 | 37 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cumsum

```
  df['F1 Running Total'] = df['F1'].cumsum()
  df['F2 Running Total'] = df['F2'].cumsum()
  df
```